# Symfony 2 form with multiple table select type

Tags: arrays, forms, symfony, collections

I'm beginner symfony developer.
I have big problem with form
i want to save data to my Table names Campaigns that looks like:

```
Campaigns:
id, user_id, recipients, message, sender, type, created
```

and the next

I have 2 tables in base for recipients system

```
contacts_groups: 
id, user_id, name, description, created
```

and

```
contacts:
id, user_id, group_id, email, city, created.
```

now let's assume that my tables have below records:

```
    contacts_groups:
        id, user_id, name, description, created
        1, 1, Test Group, Newest recipients, 2016-20-02 14:24:00
        2, 1, Awesome Group, Pro players, 2016-10-02 11:22:41
    contacts:
        id, user_id, group_id, email, city, created
        1, 1 , 1, exmple@email.com, New York, 2016-12-12 12:12:12
        2, 1 , 1, test@emailer.com, New York, 2016-12-12 12:12:12
        3, 1 , 2, proplayer@games.com, New York, 2016-12-12 12:12:12
```

Now i want to do one form with 2 tables records
Example:

```
TextField  => text for sender name row
ChoiceType => select with options with contacts_groups records
ChoiceType => select with options with contacts where group_id == choosed contacts_groups record above.
```

i have that code:

```
class CampaignsType extends AbstractType{  


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $Campaigns = $options['data'];
    $user      = $Campaigns->tmpusr; // variable transferred from the controller ( logged user id )

    $builder
          ->add('sender', TextType::class, array(
             'trim'     => true,
             'label'    => 'Odbiorca',
             'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
             'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => '11')
                ))
         ->add('recipients', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Grupa odbiorców',
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
            'class' => 'MyAppPanelBundle:ContactsGroups',
            'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->select('u')
                    ->add('where', 'u.user_id =  ' . $user)
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC');

            },
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
                 ));     
}
```

Do someone know how to add next field with contacts from database where `group_id` will be same as id of choosed group ?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: To achieve that You need to use ajax to send request with selected `group` and as response get list of `contacts` [doc chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  by Ajax:

- Ad this in your CampaignsType:

  ```
      ->add('contact', ChoiceType::class, array(
          'required' => true,
          'placeholder' => 'choose contact'
      ))
  ```
- in your view:

  ```
                  <div class="form-group">
                      {{ form_label(form.contact, label|default(null), { 'label_attr': { 'class': 'font-secondary' } }) }}
                      {{ form_widget(form.contact, {'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}} )}}
                      {{ form_errors(form.contact) }}
                  </div>
  ```
- in your controller:

`

```
/**
 * @Route("/select/contact", name="_select_contact")
 */
public function contactsAction(Request $request) {
    $group_id = $request->request->get('group_id');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $contacts = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Contact')->getContacts($group_id);
    return new JsonResponse($contacts);
}
```

- in your js file:

  ```
           $("#campaigns_group").change(function () {
              var data = {
                  group_id: $(this).val()
              };
             //$('form').spin();
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: Routing.generate('_select_contact'),
                  data: data
              }).done(function (response) {
                  var $contacts_selector = $('#campaigns_contact'),
                      contacts = response.contact;
                  $contacts_selector.html('<option>choise contact</option>');
                  for (var i = 0, total = contacts.length; i < total; i++) {
                      $contacts_selector.append('<option value="' + contacts[i].id + '">' + contacts[i].email + '</option>');
                  }

              }).fail(function () {
                  alert("error");
              }).always(function () {
                  //$('form').find('.spinner').hide()
              });
          });
  ```

Just create the getContacts() in your in contact repository and ajust the javascript to fill your needs.

Hope this help!